# Is the category of convergence spaces cartesian-closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, cartesian-closed-categories

[Convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space#definitions) are a generalization of topological spaces; we denote the category of convergence spaces with continuous maps with ${\bf Conv}$. Is ${\bf Conv}$ [cartesian-closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category)?

Comment: According to the nLab page, $\mathbf{Conv}$ is a quasitopos, hence *a fortiori* even *locally* cartesian closed.  However, it doesn't give a citation or proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seemed to be several slightly different notions of convergence spaces that were considered extensively in the 70ies. So I apologize if the following references do not actually answer your question (because I am missing some subtle differences between the definitions used in the papers below and the definition you linked to).

For the convergence spaces of Cook and Fischer, Theorem 5 in the following paper should prove that they are cartesian closed:

- H.R. Fischer and C.H. Cook. On Equicontinuity and Continuous Convergence. Math. Ann. 159 (1965), pp. 94-104. [(available here)](https://eudml.org/doc/182674)

For a slightly different notion of convergence, the $L\ast$-spaces, there is the following paper:

- G.A. Edgar. A Cartesian closed category for topology.
  General Topology and Appl. 6 (1976), no. 1, 65–72. [(available here)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X7690009X)

There are also uniform convergence spaces, cartesian closed by the following paper:

- R.S. Lee. The category of uniform convergence spaces is Cartesian closed.
  Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 15 (1976), no. 3, 461–465, 
  DOI: [10.1017/S0004972700022905](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972700022905).